# Function to go back 2 years, first day of last month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, date

I'm hoping to find a solution for this to automate a report I have. Basically what I'm trying to accomplish here is grabbing a date (first day of previous month, two years ago through last day of previous month current year).

So the date span if running this month would look like this: between 4/1/2013 and 3/31/2015

I have found code to get the date two years ago but I'm not able to also incorporate the month functions... Any help is very much appreciated!

For year I'm using this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(year,-2,GETDATE()),101)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First day of previous month 2 years ago:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(day, 1 - day(GETDATE()), GETDATE())))
```

Last day of last month:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, DATEADD(year,-2,GETDATE())), 0))
```

Then just do whatever logic you need with them

Comment: This worked for me! SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),dateadd(year, -2, dateadd(day, 1 - day(GETDATE()), GETDATE())),101)
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1),101)

Answer (score 1):

Your `where` clause can look something like this:

```
where date >= cast(dateadd(year, -2,
                           dateadd(month, -1, getdate() - day(getdate()) + 1)
                          ) as date) and
      date < cast(getdate() - day(getdate()) + 1 as date)
```

This makes use of the handy convenience that subtracting/adding a number to a `datetime` is the same as adding a date.  The start date says:  get the first day of the month, then subtract one month, then subtract two years.  This could have been done as `dateadd(month, -25, . . .)`, but I think separating the logic is clearer.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! I'm getting an error on the second part (end date) "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'."   
AND dateofservice >= cast(dateadd(year, -2,
                           dateadd(month, -1, getdate() - day(getdate()) + 1)
                          ) as date)
        AND
        dateofservice < cast(getdate() - day(getdate() + 1 as date)

Comment: `cast(getdate() - day(getdate()) + 1 as date)`

Answer (score 0):

This gives you two dates you are looking for:

```
SELECT
    CAST((DATEADD(yy, -2, DATEADD(d, -1 * DATEPART(dd, getdate()) + 1 , GETDATE() ))) as date) as yourTwoYearsAgoDate,
    CAST((DATEADD(d, -1 * DATEPART(dd, GETDATE()), GETDATE())) as date) as yourEndOfLastMonthDate
```

Comment: I'm getting this error, I'm on SQL server 2008, is that a problem?

Comment: Msg 243, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Type date is not a defined system type.

Answer (score 0):

Given a reference date (e.g. "today"),

```
declare @today date = '23 April 2015'
```

- The 1st of the month is computed by subtracting 1 less than the day number of the current month:

  ```
  select first_of_current_month = dateadd(day,1-day(@today),@today)
  ```
- The last day of the previous month is day 0 of the current month, so to get the last day of the previous month, just subtract the current day number:

  ```
  select last_of_previous_month = dateadd(day,-day(@today),@today)
  ```
- Moving two years back is easy:

  ```
  select two_years_back = dateadd(year,-2, @today )
  ```

Putting it all together, this should do you:

```
declare @today date = '23 April 2015'

select *
  first_day_of_current_month =                  dateadd(day,1-day(@today),@today),
  last_day_of_previous_month =                  dateadd(day, -day(@today),@today)   ,
  date_from                  = dateadd(year,-2, dateadd(day,1-day(@today),@today) ) ,
  date_thru                  =                  dateadd(day, -day(@today),@today)
```

yielding the expected results:

```
first_day_of_current_month: 2015-04-01
last_day_of_previous_month: 2015-03-31  
date_from                 : 2013-04-01
date_thru                 : 2015-03-31
```

So you should be able to say something like this:

```
select *
from foo t
where t.transaction_date between dateadd(year,-2, dateadd(day,1-day(@today),@today) )
                             and dateadd(day, -day(@today),@today)
```

If you have to deal with `datetime` values rather than `date`, its easier to not use `between` and say something like this:

```
declare @today date = current_timestamp -- get the current date without a time component

select *
from foo t
where t.transaction_date >= dateadd(year,-2, dateadd(day,1-day(@today),@today) )
  and t.transaction_date <  dateadd(year, 0, dateadd(day, -day(@today),@today)
```

[superfluous addition of 0 years added for clarity]

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful in understanding date functions more clearly for sure!